# shuffle or not when splitting train and test set

Tags: shuffle, cross-validation

I need a model to predict a class. So i should split my data to train, validation and test set. At first, I shuffle my data (80 % for train set and 20% for test set). Then because i should determine some hyper parameters, i split my train set using 10-fold cross validation. Finally, i train my model using train set(80% of data) and specified hyper parameters. 
I have a question. Is it wrong that i shuffle my data at first and then split them? some researchers believe if you want to claim your model can predict future data, you should not shuffle data. you should choose the last 20% of data as test set. Is it right? can i shuffle my data? can you please introduce me an academic book or paper to address my issue? 
thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @Atena, could you refer some works/links of the researchers who advise not to shuffle the data?

Comment: Hi @AzkarioRizky. My professor said. I do not have a link and posted this question to get a link.

Answer (score 4):

Irrespective of any ML technique, there can be different way to evaluate your results. In your problem, you have to shuffle the data first, then split into train and test sets. This shuffling should be random; to avoid any bias, you repeat this process several times and then report the average results. You can also compute the standard deviation of your error/accuracy to observe if the results are varying too much or not. If yes, then may be your model is not learning properly and you may need to try other method or increase data or do something else.
For NLP type of problem Goolge advice for shuffling, you can check here
[Step 3: Prepare Your Data](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification/step-3)

Answer (score 3):

Better to shuffle.  If the order of examples is such that earlier examples are unlike later examples, splitting in order might cause the training and test data to be significantly different, thus making the cross validation less meaningful.  Shuffling will lessen the likelihood of this.

Comment: if i shuffle, can i claim my model can predict future data? my data are produced by smart home sensors and are ordered by time, but the way i choose my features are Independent of time